# c# visual studio textbox into textfile

Tags: c#, text-files

I'm new with visual studio c#. This is maybe a stupid question but I find no solution for next code.
I'm trying to import a textbox (this works) and I want to import these into a text file.

```
    private void Rbalast_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string balastR = Rbalast.Text;

    }
    private void EXPORT_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("d:/VAR/200_runSheet_Tests/.txt");
    file.Write(balastR);
    file.Close();
}
```

I think it is because of the private void but I find no solution to change this.

Comment: scope my friend. take a look at this.. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx

Comment: `balastR` is a local variable, won't be able to access it in a different method. Just do `file.Write(Rbalast.Text);`

Comment: That is a solution @PoweredByOrange. But that still won't help the OP with the obvious lack of knowledge about variable scope

Comment: *[meta-comment]* Thanks for including the code that hasn't worked for you. Those who have commented on this being a scoping issue are, of course, correct, but for future reference, it might help to include the error message you're getting as well. This question wasn't too bad for those of us with experience in the language, and including the code was definitely enough, but if you get onto more complicated issues, it'll be nice to get that habit early.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is the lack of knowledge in variable scope.

To solve this, you have two options.

1) place the variable `balastR` above the method `Rbalast_TextChanged` in the class scope, which will allow you to use it in the `EXPORT_Click` as you are currently doing.

2) Go by `PoweredByOrange` suggestion, and just replace `file.Write(balastR);` with `file.Write(Rbalast.Text);`

Comment: Would you suggest someone follow the first option here? It seems like keeping a local field in sync with the TextBox text (something accessible from the same scopes, essentially, as the field would be) introduces an unnecessary layer of complexity that's likely to cause bugs.

Comment: That is very true @MatthewHaugen. However, listing the first option should help with `why` the OP's current solution wasn't working, and what variable scope means. Even if the 2nd suggestion is a better one.